# What is a replacement for deprecated v1/history/get_transaction?

Tags: nodeos, transactions, api

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_transaction-1 Api docs says that history plugin is deprecated. So v1/history/get_transaction is deprecated as well. Many eos nodes don't support it now. 
I found new state history plugin https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/state_history_plugin but it has no api yet. 
so what endpoint should I use as a replacement for getting info about particular transaction?

Answer (score 1):

History plugin is deprecated as it costs a lot of RAM and it is an expensive resource to be maintained by nodes. Some nodes migrated to state_history_plugin with Hyperion on it. This is the most workable tool for node's history and it has a lot of support. Actually this tool rocks.

For example eosrio and the junglenet official nodes are working with Hypeion as an API for node's history. Here are the API documentation: https://eos.hyperion.eosrio.io/v2/docs/index.html#/history/

Connect to a node which uses Hyperion and you will have the same history functionality as before